# How do I align a background Image on my Scaffold?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

I have a page where I where I want to set this golden border around my wheel on my Scaffold. 
This is my code:

```
 Widget spinningWheel(context) {
    double realWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
      //color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withAlpha(180),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Spinwheel(
          shouldDrawCenterPiece: true,
          wheelPaint: Paint()..color = Colors.red,
          sectorDividerPaint: Paint()..color = Colors.black,
          centerPiecePaint: Paint()..color = Colors.black,
          items: items,
          size: realWidth * 0.9,
          onChanged: (val) {
            if (this.mounted) setState(() {});
          },
          select: select,
          shouldDrawDividers: true,
          wheelOrientation: pi / 8,
          autoPlay: false,
          hideOthers: false,
          shouldDrawBorder: false,
          shouldHighlight: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the dependency I'm using: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinwheel

This is what my wheel looks like 
[image]

And this is the border I want to insert:[image]

Comment: try using stack widget

Comment: the answer below does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Stack Widget  and set alignment accordingly this is the demo and make sure you are using transparent background images :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: new Image.asset(
              'assets/yellow_circle.jpg',
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height/2,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: new Image.asset(
              'assets/red_circle.png',
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height/2,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]